# Send an Image as a logo in SharePoint Online Email Send API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate, flow, sharepoint-email

I want to send an Email over the SharePoint Online Email send API, but I want to attach and show an image as a logo.

I can convert the image to a base64 source, but it only shows the sources. I want to see the image not only text.

Here is my Screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To show the image in email body, you have to use the `img` tag instead of `a` tag.

For example:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

Comment: Thank you! That was easy, but it shows the attachment. Can I get ride of it?

Comment: Is it showing image in email body as well as image an email attachment?

Comment: Hi @Matthias, can you please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? Your action on this thread will be greatly appreciated!